Cannot load model from model registry in MLFlow by raise different directory
I attempted to load the model from model registry but failed. Here is the details.
I create the experiment using mlflow.set_experiment()
experiment = mlflow.create_experiment(
        name=exp_name, 
        artifact_location="artifact_location", 
        tags={"env":"dev", "version":"1.0.0"}
    )

I used artifact_location as my artifact directory. Which is located outside of /mlruns.
Then I registered my best model in model registry with
best_run_id = best_run.run_id
model_uri = f"runs:/{best_run_id}/model"

mlflow.register_model(model_uri=model_uri, 
                      name="cat_classifier")

After that I try to load the registered model with
model_name = "cat_classifier"
model_version = 1
model_uri = f"models:/{model_name}/{model_version}"
load_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)

but failed with the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[366], line 4
      2 model_version = 1
      3 model_uri = f"models:/{model_name}/{model_version}"
----> 4 load_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)

........

OSError: No such file or directory: '/home/User/workplace/cat/artifact_location/0eb40601413841e78f8b7b89fbf82be7/artifacts/models/.'


Then I checked /home/User/workplace/cat/artifact_location/0eb40601413841e78f8b7b89fbf82be7 which I did not found the /artifacts/models/., but I only contains
|-- model 
     |-- conda.yaml
     |-- MLModel
     |-- model.pkl
     |-- python_env.yaml
     |-- requirement.txt

Do I have done wrong by using artifact_location as the new path, which cause the failure of loading the registered model?
MLFlow UI showed the registered model, which I assumed it existed physically. I even successfully did alias for it, but still failed to load.
Appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you.

UPDATE (1/8/2024, 2:03 pm)
I am not solving the issue totally but, I create new experiment with artifact_location=Path.cwd().joinpath("mlruns").as_uri(). Then I register the model and load the registered model and finally worked fine.
I think MLflow should clear on their documentation as per giving a freedom to create the user own artifact location, as using custom location would mess up the process of loading the registered model. Better stick to use /mlruns as the root directory for all the tracking.
The problem of using custom artifact location and load the registry model is not solve yet.
